# How to establish a fast and reliable S3 to EC2 connection

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

EC2 provides a very convenient, on-demand scalable mechanism to execute distributable(parallel-izable) processes and S3 provides a reliable storage service.

I was trying to employ EC2 nodes for a ETL & analytics process, this process needs large amount of data(100GB - 1TB) ingested very quickly (and several times in a day) and adequate compute resources to be made available for a short duration.

The above design needs

1. A high-bandwidth/fast connection between S3 and EC2.
2. S3--> EC2 connection should also be reliable since scheduling of starting, pumping-in data, executing processes and terminating nodes has to be done as soon as possible not just to save costs but also because SLA's are involved.

But as yet

1. The only means of pulling data out of S3 seems to be via http and hence it is constrained by the download bandwidths of the EC2 nodes.
2. Also the data ingestion goes over the internet and hence can be unreliable enough for strict scheduling purposes necessitating adequate buffering across jobs.

In a private data-center setup one can setup a faster (say 10Gbps) dedicated line between storage and physical nodes.

Are there any possible alternatives/services options in case of aws that can address the above requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends, hugely, on all sorts of things - how much network activity the other EC2 instances on the same physical server are doing, the particular S3 node you're hitting at any one time, whether you're in the same region as your S3 endpoint, etc.

You can benchmark yourself, but even then it'll vary a lot. I've gotten multiple megabytes per second at times and a couple hundred kilobytes at other times.

Comment: amazon havent published anything about this on its website, is there any other source to get this information? Is there a different pricing model that allow flexibility to choose transfer speeds.

Comment: There is no such information, because **it varies**. The only ways to increase AWS network speed is by using the cluster instances, which get 10 Gigabit connections between servers, or by using AWS's expensive dedicated instances (http://aws.amazon.com/dedicated-instances/) to control the effects of other people on your servers.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a better answer now.

There is a separate service [Data pipeline](http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline), which provides reliable data transfer between S3 and EC2

Answer (score 2):

At least I found this recently (though it maybe available for sometime). Cloudberry offers really fast way to transfer data from S3 to EC2. The speed ranges from 40MBPS to 50MBPS. Here's the process. download cb s/w from http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx. Connect to S3. once the files are seen right click on file to copy and select the weburl. This will show the weburl for the file. Copy the whole url and on AWS VM use wget to get the url contents ( wget [copied url]

I am still looking for tools to copy data from VM to S3. S3cmd is slow and breaks too frequently.

Comment: Not sure that answers the question, but possibly helpful to someone I guess.

Comment: this is interesting...what you are saying is that accessing S3 files through their urls directly is much faster(and reliable) than that of using S3cmd. This might possibly have very little to do with cloudberry per se but just the nature of access native/api vs REST/htttp and the fact that download and upload speeds of EC2 nodes and S3 isnt bad most of the time.

Comment: actually s3cmd does not have any native interface(it is a separate independent open source tool). In fact the only protocol seems to be http in which case, it is hard to understand differences among tools e.g. wget, curl, aws sdk, s3cmd etc..except for the the possibility that a tool may not be performant or buggy.