# Upload Speed of Files from EC2 to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How can we improve the upload speed of files from EC2 to S3, when the EC2 machine and S3 in different regions?

I have created a file which is of 1GB, and i need to upload the same to S3. Here the EC2 machine and S3 bucket were located in different regions(but Same Country)
Both were in US but the region is East and west

Anyone please assist on this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do here. You are going to be limited to the available bandwidth between each datacenter.

You do have the option of moving your instance or bucket, to the other region. How much work this will be will depend on how much data you have in your bucket, or how you are currently using your instance.

Answer (score 0):

A similar Question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041166/how-to-establish-a-fast-and-reliable-s3-to-ec2-connection/17016260#17016260)

There is a separate service [Data pipeline](http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline), which provides reliable data transfer between S3 and EC2